# What does Microsoft Azure offer for hosting PHP7 + MariaDB app with automated high availability / scalability?

Tags: azure

We want to make our website hosting auto-scalable to be able to handle peaks in traffic using Microsoft Azure. The website runs on php7 and uses MariaDB 10.1, which Azure services/structure do you advise to use so we can migrate quickly and handle the traffic?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's very broad and opinion-soliciting (and not a programing question). There's simply no "right" way to answer this. We know nothing about your app and its traffic. We know nothing about your preferred OS, your deployment methods, your storage needs, your monitoring/tools, etc. There are dozens of services in Azure. And they're all enumerated and documented on the Azure website. I'd suggest starting there and learning about the different offerings. Then, ask specific programming questions here.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Normally I'd agree with you that the question is far too vague and possibly off-topic, but Azure is a bit confusing with so many different services and many people don't know where to start their research. It kind of makes it a tough one for SO

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann, indeed, that was a reason for my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options in Azure to do this:

1) You could use Azure Web Apps to host the PHP7 app and turn on Autoscaling to dynamically scale in/out to handle load. This is a pure PaaS solution and the one I'd recommend if it's feasible to host your app in an Azure Web App.

2) You could use Virtual Machines with Scale Sets configured to host your app / workload. This is an IaaS solution and does require quite a bit more work, but may be necessary if you require full access to install and configure the server for your application needs.

3) There's also Cloud Services that's somewhat of an in-between PaaS and IaaS service...

For MariaDB... I'm not familiar with that, it's not something Azure has a PaaS service for. You may need to host MariaDB in a VM and implement replication of some kind to a secondary / backup VM for failover.

Anyway, this is a really simple answer to your very loaded question. Hopefully this gives you an idea of what direction to research and where to go from here. :)